# Using tooltip in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to use tooltip in my cakephp application , i have excess data in my database table so i just want to display starting few words and when the user moves his cursor than i want entire data to be displayed in the form of a box structure....

I am not able to us the tooltip plugin . I just copied the  tooltip folder in my apps/plugin file and later in my controller file i used like this

```
 public $helpers = array('tooltip');
```

But when i run my file i get this error.

```
tooltipHelper could not be found.
```

The tooltip plugin has got many files in it. I am not sure which one to use as the helper file..I am new to cakephp can anyone help me out with using the plugin ????

Comment: the casing is important: Tooltip would be ucfirst

Comment: If it's a plugin it would probably be `Tooltip.Tooltip`

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like this:

```
$('title.tooltip').qtip();
```

if iam doing like this below

```
<title class="tooltip"></title>.
```

orelse you can also use like this

```
$title = "This is the crazy little Easy Tooltip Text.";
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('add.gif').''.$title.'',
'javascript:void(0)', array('class' => 'tooltip', 'onclick' => $dialog, 
'escape' => false));
```

Check this out on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

You can see this http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/andy/2008/06/25/prototip-helper it may help you alot

If you want to use in simple html try like this

```
<a id="my_tooltip" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="mytool">Hello</a>
```

Comment: where do i need to use it ??

Comment: @PavanK I have sent you another link also....see it...for your better way of coding...\