# How to display inline text in cackphp

Tags: cakephp

Please see below image

[image]

I have one query about how to display inline text near text box in `cakephp`.

Thanks,
Ramesh Prajapati

Comment: Please add it to your question ... nevermind ... i did ...

Comment: Showing a little more effort in asking your questions usually results in better answers. You could for example mention your exact CakePHP version, show what you've already tried, explain whether your problem is CSS and/or Form helper related, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894348/using-tooltip-in-cakephp) . I believe that's what you're looking for ...

(assuming you want the tooltip...)

Comment: thanks for the response but i would to like display text according to the image

Comment: If it answered your question, you can mark it as answered (or even upvote it ... )

Answer (score 0):

The FormHelper->input() method accepts a 'after' key in the options.
There you can insert your custom HTML.

See http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-FormHelper.html#_input

So something like this should work

```
$this->Form->input('my_field', array('after' => '<span class="verify">Verify</span>'));
```